# Rails form_with defaulting to incorrect method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using Rails 6. I have a route that defines a get request:

```
namespace :admin do
    get '/machines/search', to: 'machines#search', as: 'search_machines'
end
```

Then, I have a `form_with` that sets the `url` to the `route`. When the form is loaded, the HTML that's generated for the form contains a `method="post"` instead of `method="get"` which is what I would've expected since the route is a GET request and not a POST. I can add the `method: "get"` parameter to the `form_with` and this fixes the issue but I don't understand why Rails didn't pick up the correct method initially.

```
<%= form_with url: admin_search_machines_path() do |i| %>
    <%= i.text_field :q, placeholder: "Search", autocomplete: "off", class: "debounce-form-submit form-control" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: @dbugger I understand that, what I am confused about is that Rails didn't automatically set the method for me like it does when I pass a model to a `form_with` instead of a `route`.

Comment: You can (and should!) omit empty sets of brackets on method calls with no arguments, as in `admin_search_machines_path` is sufficient here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with) `form_with` does default to `POST` if `method` is not specified. Which is not 100% correct, as it will switch to `PATCH` (via hidden field trick) if the model is persisted ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/070d4afacd3e9721b7e3a4634e4d026b5fa2c32c/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1530)).

Up to today, the code does not look at the route itself to specify the `method`.

I think the (backwards incompatible) automagic you suggest is not totally off, though. You might ask about that in the [rubyonrails forums](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/) and get feedback whether this would be a welcomed change. Personally, I never expected it to inspect the route. Also, you might have the same route with `post` and `get` methods, which would make lookup more involved than what meets the eye on first sight.